# How can I find out if I am in recovery mode in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Once Ubunutu (10.04 LTS) server has booted, is there a way to check to see if it is in recovery mode or "normal" mode?

I've got a server that has been running a while, but I'm not sure how it was booted, and I'm hoping there is a way to check without just rebooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Recovery mode" means that you're booting into runlevel 1. Type `runlevel` to check which runlevel you are running. Another way is to install `sysv-rc-conf` to see which services isn't loaded in runlevel 1.

Comment: Details about different runlevels can be found at at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Debian_Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Debian_Linux)